# Beamer multilevel lists with the Madrid theme

Tags: beamer, enumerate

I wish to have multilevel list which includes the previous level number, i.e.,

1. Item

   1.1 Subitem
   ...

However, it seems that the `Madrid` theme does not allow this.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}
\frame{
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Subitem 2.1
    \item Subitem 2.2
      \begin{enumerate}
      \item Subsubitem 2.2.1
      \item Subsubitem 2.2.2
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
}
\end{document}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to keep the `ball` style numbers the `Madrid` theme by defult uses and just add the numbers of the preivous levels or do you want to replicate the style shown in the left part of the image, while at the same time using the `Madrid` theme? For the latter, `\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. The second option is what I meant. The first option would be problematic because of the enlarged numbers.

Comment: @leandriis Would you like to write an answer?